# Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to link my mlab with my models but it's throwing me an error like this:

> `throw new TypeError('Undefined type` ' + name + '`at`' + path +
>
> ^
>
> TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `required`
> Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

In my **folder models** I've got:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProjectSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
email: String,
description: String,
image: {data: Buffer, contentType: String },
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
location: String, //{street: String, number: String, zip: String, city: String, required: true},
fixedAmount: Number, required: true,
wantedAmount: Number,
receivedAmount: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

and almost the same with my UserSchema...

I have also an **index.js** there :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports.connect = (uri) => { 
mongoose.connect(uri); 
// plug in the promise library: 
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => { 
  console.error(`Mongoose connection error: ${err}`); 
  process.exit(1);
});

// load models 
require('./user'); 
require('./project');
require('./common');
};
```

**In my server.js :**

```
const config = require('./config.js');

// connect to the database and load models 
require('./server/models').connect(config.dbUrl);
```

and in my **config.js:**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = {
  'port': process.env.PORT || 5000, 
  'dbUrl':     `mongodb://${process.env.USER_DB}:${process.env.PASSWORD_DB}@ds123930.mlab.com:23930/kickass`, 
 "jwtSecret": "a secret phrase !"
}
```

Comment: Ignore the previous comment, it was based on the unformatted code.

In the schema, `fixedAmount: Number, required: true` should be `fixedAmount: {type: Number, required: true}`

Comment: Thank you it was a silly mistake hahaha ^^'

Comment: By the way i've got an 400 error  while i want to submit my form, i could log the data which i'm writting in my inputs but i can't send it